# server-side restful api analytics

Tags: api, rest, analytics

I have a rails-based restful server-side api.

I want to know what services are called the most, their response time, etc.

So this is sort of web analytics, but it's for server-side operation.

Is there any free service out there that can help out( google analytics is a good analogy)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to analyze your logs?

It is a very good way to get the statistics you are looking for without using an external service

Here is a link: [Rails log analyzer](http://rails-analyzer.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

try Apigee http://www.apigee.com/ it's free and could give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. A lot of services are for web analytics, this means they super general, and it's hard to configure it properly.

What I can suggest you is to use some kind of APM. There is one especially for Rails - https://appsignal.com/. But it's not free, price starts from 15 euro / month for 250K of requests.